# Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]

Tags: wcf, net.tcp

I have been using http for all these and when i am working with net.tcp and when adding the reference i am getting an error like

Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http].

my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="servicebehave" name="WcfServ.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="" name="nettcp" contract="WcfServ.IService1" />

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:51560/Service1.svc" />
           <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/Service1.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="netTcpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="servicebehave">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Can anybody tell me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: What is your hosing environment?

Comment: IIS 6.0 but i dint host the service,when i am adding the service i am getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't host net.tcp under IIS 6, it supports only HTTP(s). So you are limited with HTTP bindings only (basic, ws or 2007). In order to provide net.tcp and other protocols, WAS is required. You can activate it standalone, but I advice you to install it both with IIS 7 (it is installed as a part of it), because IIS 7 gives a convinient service management platform in addition.

Another solution it so change the hosting environment to make it self-hosted or service-hosted, using ServiceHost class instance, which supports tcp protocol.

Comment: Maybe he should assign an address to the endpoint and not an empty string modifying the baseAddress too.

Comment: @FrancescoDeLisi No, it is not required. Two endpoint can have same relative adresses in case if they are using different protocols. Even if they are empty - ""

Comment: But i am not even hosting the service i am just adding reference to the client so i am getting the error how can i get rid of it??

Comment: What do you mean in term "hosting"? When you try to add refecence, it assumed that the service is hosted somewhere. When you try to get MEX point information, IIS tries to launch your service, it fails because of net.tcp and returns you your error.

Comment: So first of all i have to host the service and i can add as a reference to my client??

Comment: Yes, first you have to host your service and make sure it is available be turning on your MEX point and promting you service adress in any browser adress input.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure your wcf service for net.tcp in **IIS 7** please refer to this answer:

[WCF Service Base Address Http and netTcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012765/wcf-service-base-address-http-and-nettcp/24937798#24937798)

Regards